# adding the_custom_logo(); to header

Tags: css

i want to show logo on navbar section.the logo appears but i cant control it with css.

```
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light  sticky-top" style="background-color:rgb(3, 0, 180);" role="navigation">
  <div class="container" >
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" > 
       <img src="<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>" height="42" width="42">



      </a>
```

i typed notes on screen picture:

[image]

https://i.ibb.co/w7rSkw3/11-A234233232ds-z.png

Comment: Why is `wp_head()` there? That function needs to be inside the `<head>` element.

Comment: @jacob thank you for this info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue you're running into is putting `the_custom_logo()` inside of an `<img>` tag. The function already outputs a full image tag, plus a link to the homepage wrapped around it. So, replace this

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" > 
    <img src="<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>" height="42" width="42">
</a>
```

with this

```
<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
```

to get rid of the first and third arrow in your screenshot.

Comment: so how can i size the logo?

Comment: Inspect it once it's output and figure out what CSS classes/elements/etc. you can target.

Comment: i am sorry bc i dont understand.can you explain with a example code?

Comment: The example code is above. First get that running. Then in your web browser, use your developer tools to inspect the element, and then you can find what classes, elements, etc. you need to use to target that specific logo. You may need to take some CSS classes if you're not familiar with that process. :)

Comment: can you look at my question again bc i changed class options but i dont know what is my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure you need to add or edit any classes? You could target `img.custom-logo` and still style however you wish, including enforcing a certain size.

Comment: thanks for ur help.its solved